# Google Fit: Create a Session from data collected using the Recording API

Tags: android, google-fit

In the Android Google Fit SDK, is it possible to create a Session from data *already* collected using the Recording API (i.e. already in the fitness store)?

I've tried using the `DataSource` from a `DataSet` from a `DataReadRequest`, but that causes the `SessionInsertRequest` to fail with a 5015 error:

```
Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 5015, resolution=null}
```

Here is my read request:

```
DataReadResult result = Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(apiClient,
        new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
                .bucketByActivitySegment(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build())
        .await();
```

Here is my session insert request:

```
SessionInsertRequest insertRequest = new SessionInsertRequest.Builder()
            .setSession(session)
            .addDataSet(result.getBuckets().get(0).getDataSets().get(0))
            .build();
```

**The root problem**: I need to attach some metadata to each of the user's activities and thought Sessions would fit this problem best. If there's a better way please let me know.

Comment: The Sessions API guide already shows how to use the Recording API to create a session, but it sounds like your question is about creating sessions from data _already_ recorded and stored via the Recording API, i.e. you want to get data via the History API and reinsert it as a session with metadata. Is this your question?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Basically, I just need to have an ID associated with each activity segment.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Here's what the status object from my insertSession call looks like: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 5015, resolution=null}. I've also edited my question to show the sessionInsertRequest I'm building.

Answer (score 1):

So after a little digging I found out what the 5015 error means. It's documented in the [`FitnessStatusCodes`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessStatusCodes):

> public static final int **INCONSISTENT_PACKAGE_NAME**
>
> Status code denotes that app attempted to insert data for a DataSource that does not match the app's package name.
>
> Constant Value: 5015

So it looks like if you want to make your app have metadata connected to activities, you would have to subscribe to data from your own app.

**EDIT**: *The below suggestion was attempted, but didn't work. I leave it here because we don't know exactly* why *it didn't work and so to what extent it is wrong is unsure and how to interpret storing data "on behalf of your app" is left open.*

I previously thought you needed to make your own `DataSource`, but according to the [`RecordingApi.subscribe(GoogleApiClient, DataType)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/RecordingApi.html#subscribe(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType)) you can specify the `DataType` and it'll use the default `DataSource`. Moreover, the [Recording API Guide](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record) seems to indicate that it will be added to the Fitness Store with your app's name on it ("on behalf of your app"). So it would just be

```
Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT);
```

Though, also in the `subscribe` documentation it says

> If the requested subscription already exists, the request will be a no-op and **SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED** will be returned.

So I'm not quite sure what that means for two different apps subscribing to data and if both app package names are stored in the `DataSource`

Comment: Thanks for looking for this, but unfortunately I don't think this solves my problem because data from the Recording API is always inserted into a datastore with package name com.google.android.gms (i.e. Google Play Services).

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: The [RecordingAPI Guide](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record) seems to suggest otherwise: "If the subscription is added successfully, Google Fit will store fitness data of type TYPE_ACTIVITY_SAMPLE in the fitness history on behalf of your app."

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tested out your solution, but when I performed the same DataReadRequest (from above) every data point was still attached to the "com.google.android.gms" data source (Google Play Services). That "on your behalf" line seems misleading, as datapoints are always inserted with the Google Play Services package name.

Comment: Hm, I guess you'd have to create your own `DataSource` if you want it to insert with your own package name then.